# "Mathematica running" not shown in Mathematica Icon in 11.1

Tags: mac-os-x, system

I wonder whether this is a singular problem to my environment or not: In Mathematica 11.0.x the icon of Mathematica showed a circle around the Mathematica symbol when Mathematica was running, so one could see, whether a calculation is running or not. On my machine now an executing calculation is not indicated.

System:
MacOS 10.12.3, MacBookPro, Late 2016 TouchBar, 16GB RAM, Mathematica 11.1

Can this behavior be confirmed by others?

Comment: It works fine here, also macOS 10.12.3, M11.1.0.  I tested with `Pause[10]`. It took maybe 1-2 seconds before the circle appeared.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thank you for this information, then I´m doing a bit of clean-up on my machine....

Comment: Perhaps it's worth reporting to Wolfram.

Comment: same here. just noticed it. MMA 11. 3 on mac OS 10.13.6